# right bottom corner arrow menu android

Tags: android

How can I create design as show below.

Right side corner as bottom arrow. is there any default menu bar that I can provide any view in android.[image]

Comment: okay. it is spinner. if I want to open at up side than how can I do?

Comment: for this you need to use animations and inflate layout into your current xml or activity

Comment: I can't get you Praveena_Pinki